# Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS Raspberry Pi3b+ can't boot/install

Tags: boot, server, raspberrypi

I've a Rasberry Pi 3b+ and want to run 'Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS' on it.
I downloaded the 'ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso' and used Etcher to put that onto my microSD card.

I unmounted it then and tried to start the Raspberry Pi after I inserted the card into the device.

The green LED has flashed a few times, but stopped after about 20 seconds. The Monitor didn't show anything, and only the red LED shined.

Comment: The raspberry pi uses a ARM processor; not intel/amd (x86_64) so you grabbed the wrong architecture.  (Try grabbing it from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi-2-3  ; the ISO you grabbed is for amd/intel x86_64 machines)

Comment: I'm user of orance pc, what is similar to raspberry. Used specially prepared images from official website, and other hand made.

Answer (score 0):

Get image for RPi 3B+ from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi). This page have install instructions also. Etcher is not suitable for that. This images designed to boot on RPi, others will not work.

Short install inctructiuons:

```
xzcat ubuntu.img.xz | sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/mmcblkX

Or using ddrescue (must decompress the image first):

unxz ubuntu.img.xz
sudo ddrescue -D -d --force ubuntu.img /dev/mmcblkX
```

Rename */dev/mmcblkX* to your sdcard device. If you installing from windows - just unpack and write image by `Win32DiskImager`